# Show UIButton Created in Code in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6

In Xcode 6, can you have a UIButton property in your header file display in interface builder by setting the property as IBInspectable? The button is created entirely in code. Something like `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable UIButton *directions;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uibutton are inspectable type. But why don't you just use a IBOutlet?
IBInspectable is just a way to design a set of none UI properties which can be then be accessible in IB to help you customize your class via the attribute inspector. 
If you want to have a preview of your custom button, you should use IBDesignable, but in this case it doesn't apply to a property but a class. 
IBDesignable allow to have a preview in IB of your view.

Check this article: http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/